# PHP input system with multiple drop down menu's

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have a Php input system with 5 fields:  Number, Link, Article, Name and Date. I'm trying to have the information brought inside 2 different drop down menu's. For example in the database I have:

1........http link.....Bloomberg Links........**Bloomberg**....2017-03-22
2........http link.....Forbes Links...........**Forbes**.......2017-03-22

So, I need the articles with the Bloomberg Name to go into the Bloomberg drop down menu and the articles with the Forbes Name to go into the Forbes drop down menu.

Currently, I have the 2 drop down menu's on the page and both Bloomberg and Forbes articles are going into both menu's because I don't know how to make them go into the proper drop down menu.  The page is http://www.althedge.xyz/new.html

I'd appreciate is someone could show me the code that would make the Bloomberg articles go into the Bloomberg drop down menu and the Forbes articles go into the Forbes drop down menu.  The html code and the php code are below.  Thanks for the help?

```
<?php

// Database Settings 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_PORT', '*****');
define('DB_USER', '*****');
define('DB_PASS', '*****');
define('DB_NAME', '*****');

// Connection to Database
$database = new MySQLi(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);

$sql = 'SELECT * '
        . ' FROM crypto ORDER BY Date DESC, Number DESC';

$resultSet = $database->query($sql);

$currentDate = false;
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())

{
if ($row['Date'] != $currentDate){
 echo
$row['Date'] ;

$currentDate = $row['Date'];  
}


echo


'<a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer"href="'.  
 $row["Link"].
 '"style="text-decoration: none;"'.
 '">'. 
 $row["Article"].
 '</A>'.
 '</sub><div style="height: 25px;"></div></li><li>';


 } 


$html .= '</ul></li></table>';

echo $html;

?>

<html >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>hedge</title>




<style>

li {
    line-height: 1.10;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: MesloLGL-Regular;
    src: url(/MesloLGL-Regular.ttf);
}

span *
{

   font-size: 12px !important;
}

body * { 
    background: black;
    font-family: MesloLGL-Regular !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}

body {
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.nav {
    display: block;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav .button-dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.nav li a:hover, .nav li a.dropdown-toggle.active {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav li a:hover span, .nav li a.dropdown-toggle.active span {
    color: #fff;
}

.nav li .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 999999;
}

.nav li .dropdown-menu.active {
    display: block;

}

.nav li .dropdown-menu a {
    width: 350px;

}


h3 {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
    </style>

  <script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>



  <script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>

</head>
<strong>

<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left">

<body translate="no" >

  <ul class="nav">
  <li class="button-dropdown">
  <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer"href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
 <span><u>bloomberg</u><font color="#00FF00"> new</font></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li>
  <?php include 'searchnew.php';?>

<br><br>

  <ul class="nav">
  <li class="button-dropdown">
  <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer"href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
 <span><u>coindesk</u><font color="#00FF00"> new</font></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li>
  <?php include 'searchnew.php';?>  



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-b2a7b3fe212eaa732349046d8416e00a9dec26eb7fd347590fbced3ab38af52e.js"></script>


    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    function t(t) {
        e(t).bind("click", function (t) {
            t.preventDefault();
            e(this).parent().fadeOut()
        })
    }
    e(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
        var t = e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").is(":hidden");
        e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").hide();
        e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
        if (t) {
            e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").toggle().parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active")
        }
    });
    e(document).bind("click", function (t) {
        var n = e(t.target);
        if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown")) e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").hide();
    });
    e(document).bind("click", function (t) {
        var n = e(t.target);
        if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown")) e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
    })
});
  //# sourceURL=pen.js
  </script>


</strong>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should try to seperate css, js, php, html in different files first. and then you should think about doing 2 queries one for each category or use php with an if statement to seperate them

Comment: which would you recommend would be easier?

Comment: Based on your code, the easiest solution would be to create 2 php files one for bloomberg and the other for forbes, make the query only search for those and you are done. 
But this would be bad practice.
Instead do not simply include the files which only contains the ul. Instead think about creating the whole html markup for the dropdowns via php so you would be more flexible

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the problem is I don't know how to write the code you are suggesting.  Thanks

Comment: i wrote two different approaches. Both of them have be described by me on a loose base. you should be able to pull it off ;)

Comment: Really no help at all to say use Php, I already knew that.

Comment: STEP 1: SELECT * FROM 
STEP 2: while
STEP 3: if(name matches one)
STEP 4: ECHO DATA ONE
STEP 5: else
STEP 6: ECHO DATA TWO

Step somewhere inbetween, build some kind of logic to seperate them, there are many different ways, for example checking the results, using an array to keep track.

ALTERNATE:
STEP 1: SELECT * FROM * WHERE name matches one
STEP 2: Echo all the Stuff
STEP 3: SELECT * FROM * WHERE name matches two
STEP 4: Echo all the stuff

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;`enter code here`
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me 1</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Hello World 1!</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Hello World 1!</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Hello World 1!</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me 2</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Hello World 2!</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Hello World 2!</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Hello World 2!</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not really related to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: ohhh that's fine,
than try to create different sql query with where conditions

Comment: ohhh that's fine,
than try to create different sql query with where conditions
$sql1 = "SELECT *  FROM crypto WHERE columns = 'name' ORDER BY Date DESC, Number DESC";

Comment: How would the sql statements, sql, sql1 and so on from the php code know how to go into the correct drop down menu?  For example the sql statement should bring bloomberg links into the bloomberg drop down menu and the sql1 statement should bring forbes links into the forbes drop down menu.  Thanks